# Redis as NoSQL Key/Value Database in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, redis, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I'am wondering what is the best way to use Redis NoSQL Database in CakePHP not for Caching but as regular Key/Value Store?

There is a Plugin for Redis 2.4.2 or higher, but the Plugin does not work with CakePHP 3.x: [Redis CakePHP 2.4.2 Plugin](https://github.com/Oefenweb/cakephp-redis)

What is the best way to use Redis in CakePHP 3 as regular Key/Value Database? How costly is it to upgrade the CakePHP 2.4.2 Redis-Plugin to a CakePHP 3.x Plugin. Is the migration of the Plugin the best way or is it better to create a new Datasource? (The current Redis-Plugin extends the Datasource-class.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a close look at what that datasource does, it's pretty much just a proxy to a `Redis` class instance, other than that it only handles connecting and disconnecting.

So besides having auto connect/disconnect functionality, there is pretty much no point in implementing such a datasource, and you could also just use `Redis` directly instead.

**https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#classes-and-methods**

If you'd wanted to use it as a datasource, ie have it [**accessible via the connection manager**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_get), then you'll have to implement [**`\Cake\Datasource\ConnectionInterface`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionInterface.html).

If you are looking for a datasource that acts as an ORM, that's a complete different story, and a rather complex task, see for example [**the CakePHP ElasticSearch Datasource plugin**](https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search).